# Failsafe conversion between different character encodings

Tags: c++, c, utf-8

I need to convert strings from one encoding (UTF-8) to another. The problem is that in the target encoding we do not have all characters from the source encoding and libc iconv(3) function fails in such situation. What I want is to be able to perform conversion but in output string have this problematic characters been replaced with some symbol, say '?'.

Programming language is C or C++.

Is there a way to address this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending "//TRANSLIT" or "//IGNORE" to the end of the destination charset string. Note that this is only supported under the GNU C library.

From [iconv_open(3)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv_open.3.html):

```
   //TRANSLIT
          When the string "//TRANSLIT" is appended to tocode, translitera‐
          tion is activated.  This means that when a character  cannot  be
          represented  in the target character set, it can be approximated
          through one or several similarly looking characters.

   //IGNORE
          When the string "//IGNORE" is  appended  to  tocode,  characters
          that  cannot  be represented in the target character set will be
          silently discarded.
```

Alternately, manually skip a character and insert a substitution in the output when you get -EILSEQ from [iconv(3)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Regex based on the translatable source ranges used to swap a corresponding placeholder in for any chars that don't match.